# How to select rows in a Google Sheet that contain certain words filtering by custom formula

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I need to delete all rows that do not contain `word1`, nor `word2`, nor `word3` in a given column, selecting them with the filter option for that column, and (I assume) with a custom formula.

Comment: @player0 This is an example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_74fc6ScrdbCZdO_QzYay1aANadMuhpiiNgIUQM5dtU/edit?usp=sharing), where rows that do not contain `Primaria`, `Secundaria` or `Bachillerato` in column B should be deleted.

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_74fc6ScrdbCZdO_QzYay1aANadMuhpiiNgIUQM5dtU/edit#gid=2009965671&range=A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:C; NOT(REGEXMATCH(C:C; "word1|word2|word3")))
```

where A:C is your table and C:C is the column that can't contain those words

---

if this is for filtered view try:

```
=IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(C:C; "word1|word2|word3")), 1)
```

Comment: `=IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(B:B, "Primaria|Secundaria|Bachillerato")), 1)` did the work!